# No middle-click scrolling in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Just as I started to assume this feature was ubiquitous(middle-clicking on a page, then scrolling speed/direction is relative to the distance of the pointer on the y-axis).

I can't believe this hasn't been implemented into the text editor in vs2010, I used it all the time in 2005 and 2008.

Has anyone managed to find a workaround or am I a minority user of this feature?

Comment: This feature is called auto-scroll.

Comment: I don't have any special insight, but I've heard that VS2010's UI has been reimplemented from scratch in WPF.  Maybe it's especially had to implement that feature in the new environment?  Or maybe it's a feature that they postponed?  Or forgot?

Comment: I'm also missing this feature.  I have an ergonomic mouse with three buttons but no scroll wheel.  If anyone knows a way to enable it, please let us know.

Comment: I also miss it. Hopefully it'll come in a hotifx or service pack.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an extension which makes it work (at least partially):
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3b81aea8-d022-4aa6-9b8c-16ef86cc610d

Comment: Omg, an _extension_ for mouse wheel scroll.  Now you've seen it all.

Comment: It actually doesn't work for my laptop's trackpoint scroll.

Comment: As a user of Actual Title Buttons I just noticed that it has a feature called "Drag to Scroll (Hand)" http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/help/features/dragtoscroll.php which kind of eases the problem. It allows you to assign a button which when clicked, uses the entire scrollable area as the scrollbar (can be inverted and speed can be varied). It is not a smooth scroll, but it is pretty interesting since you don't have to click on the scrollbars. And it works in the free editions which don't take extensions. It takes time to get used to, but even lets you mmb scroll in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Totally works for me; using the 3M ergonomic "vertical" mouse.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a better simple extension from the Visual Studio Gallery that adds middle click scrolling: [AutoScroller for VS 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7b2f069f-01f8-4a6a-bd46-b5b1194911e9/)

**But I recommend you to take a look to the [Microsoft Productivity Tools extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/)**. It adds middle click scrolling support to the Visual Studio 2010 IDE as well as many other improvements. After you install the extension you can enable/disable its features from menu "Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools".